# Is there a faster way to delete orphaned table entries

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I currently have 20,000 rows in the listing table, and already this query is running quite slow.

What it does is delete all listing rows where the current time is 60 seconds or more since the listing endDate and where the listing is not associated with any task.

```
DELETE
    listing
FROM
    listing
LEFT JOIN
    task
ON
    task.listingId = listing.listingId
WHERE
        task.listingId      IS NULL
    AND listing.endDate     < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)
```

Is there a faster way to delete the orphaned listing rows?

**UPDATE:**

The original (above) query takes 11.6 secs.

This equivalent bunch of queries takes 0.09 secs, but it's a lot messier and requires a bunch of PHP:

```
$q = "
    SELECT
        listingId
    FROM
        task
";
$result = mysql_query($q) or die(mysql_error());

$taskListingIds = array();

while ($task = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $taskListingIds[$task['listingId']] = NULL;
}

$q = "
    SELECT
        listingId
    FROM
        listing
    WHERE
        endDate < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)
";
$result = mysql_query($q) or die(mysql_error());

while ($listing = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    if (!array_key_exists($listing['listingId'], $taskListingIds)) {
        $q = "
            DELETE
            FROM
                listings
            WHERE
                listingId = " . $listing['listingId'] . "
        ";
        mysql_query($q) or die(mysql_error());
    }
}
```

I'll stick with this for now, but any suggestions for a fast way to do this purely with SQL would be great.

Comment: Do you have a database index on the EndDate?

Comment: I'd say the query is well written and I would have a look on defined indexes. It might help if you add a non clustered index on task.listingId and a clustered index on listing.endDate.

Comment: I'd try something like `delete from listing where not exists (select 1 from task where task.linstingId = listing.listingId) and endDate ...`. BTW can you post the query plan MySQL gives you fir your query?

Comment: I tried that just now 9000, it takes 39.7 secs vs the originals 11.6 secs.

Comment: Unfortunately i'm on shared hosting and can't perform many SQL commands, so it doesn't look like I can get the query plan. I tried indexing endDate in phpMyAdmin but it had no effect.